# Matplotlib.pyplot: how to abuse the argument `c` to plot points with different colormaps?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using an external library which has a function to autogenerate a plot using `matplotlib.pyplot`. It takes in one `numpy.ndarray` / `pandas.DataFrame` and generates a custom figure. I would like to "abuse" the `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(..., c=colors, ...)` argument such that I can `np.vstack` multiple matrices and pass in a value for colors such that I color each sub matrix with a different colormap.

```py
a = np.zeros((10, 2))
b = np.zeros((20, 2))
c = np.zeros((5, 2))

plot_mat = np.vstack(a, b, c)


colors = list(range(a.shape[0])) + list(range(b.shape[0])) + list(range(c.shape[0]))
external_fn(plot_mat, ..., c=colors)
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html)?

Comment: @QuangHoang I appreciate the useful documentation, but unfortunately I don't have access to `ax` variables from this function. I have `c` and `cmap` and `colors`.

Comment: Just curious, what's your external function? usually they are designed so as you can either pass `ax` or get `ax` from it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved actually rather easily:

```py
from matplotlib import cm
cm_a = cm.get_cmap('viridis')
cm_b = cm.get_cmap('inferno')

c_a = np.array(list(range(a.shape[0])))
c_b = np.array(list(range(b.shape[0])))

c_a = c_a / np.max(c_a)
c_b = c_b / np.max(c_b)

c = [cm_a(i) for i in c_a] + [cm_b(i) for i in c_b]
```